# Op-Amp Differentiator

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, power-electronics, inverting-amplifier

[image]

In the differentiator circuit above, resistor R<sub>1</sub> is used to limit the gain to a constant of R<sub>2</sub>/R<sub>1</sub> at high frequencies. But what is the role of capacitor C<sub>2</sub> here?

Comment: It's to suppress higher frequencies.

Comment: at very high frequency C2 is short and the opamp acts as a unity gain buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, using the standard [inverting amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Inverting_amplifier) formula and an ideal opamp, we can see that:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{v}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\text{R}_2\text{||}\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}}{\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}}=\frac{\text{R}_2\cdot\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}}{\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}}=$$
$$\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{s}+1}\cdot\frac{\text{sC}_1}{\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\text{s}+1}=\frac{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2\text{s}}{\left(1+\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\text{s}\right)\left(1+\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{s}\right)}\tag1$$

Now, when working with sinusoidal signals we can use \$\text{s}:=\text{j}\omega\$ (where \$\text{j}^2=-1\$ and \$\omega=2\pi\text{f}\$ with \$\text{f}\$ is the frequency of the input signal in Hertz). So, we get:

$$\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=\frac{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2\text{j}\omega}{\left(1+\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\text{j}\omega\right)\left(1+\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{j}\omega\right)}=\frac{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2\omega\text{j}}{\left(1+\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\omega\text{j}\right)\left(1+\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\omega\text{j}\right)}\tag2$$

So, the absolute value if given by:

$$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2\omega}{\sqrt{1+\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\omega\right)^2}\cdot\sqrt{1+\left(\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\omega\right)^2}}\tag3$$

Now, when \$\omega\to\infty\$ we get:

- When \$\text{C}_2>0\$:
  $$\lim_{\omega\to\infty}\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=0\tag4$$
- When \$\text{C}_2=0\$:
  $$\lim_{\omega\to\infty}\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1}\tag5$$

Comment: May l know which tool you are using for entering equations

Comment: @HARITO It's a modified subset version of MathJax that is supported on this site.

Answer (score 0):

The capacitor C2 is a design approach. This capacitor causes the frequency response to not just flatten out but to decrease at high frequencies.

[image]

Comment: Yeah but why is that needed (gain decreasing at high freq.), any specific reason for such design

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the circuit. It could be to reduce high frequency noise, for example. If your signal has a bit of noise/spikes at a high frequency that's not interesting for your particular circuit, it's better to get rid of it there, rather than downstream, otherwise the differentiator will amplify this noise, it could clip the opamp and corrupt the whole signal.

Comment: @JirhsKumar bobflux has nailed the reason. C2 is very commonly added to R2 on the first stage in order to mitigate high frequency noise before it is allowed into the rest of the system and the trade-offs are then more of a problem. Since this is a differentiator (by your definition) and since differentiators are noisy by definition as well, it's a good idea here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic answer but, if pressed, it is the feedback capacitor that limits the gain at high frequencies and, it is the input resistor that limits current into the opamp should an input square wave be applied. As with all these types of  circuits, it is what surrounds it (circuit wise) that may have a bigger effect than either the input resistor or feedback capacitor hence, the generic picture in your question is probably showing the input resistor as the equivalent output resistance that drives the input capacitor.